# Laravel setup failed to open stream

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to setup laravel but its proving to be a right mere! I've cloned it from github and also used composer to clone laravel and I've got both of these techniques working which is good because its something I really wanted to learn. Simpler than I thought.

However when I try to navigate to my laravel directory which is called iProject so I type into my browser localhost/iProject I get a list of directories which is not what I expected, I expected to be directed to at least the hello.php page.

I've tired another technique as described in a Net-tuts tutorial which is setting up a listening port and there I am then going through localhost:8888, but when using this technique the following error message appears:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'public/' include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
```

#### Setting up Virtual Host (as per responses received)

When I setup the virtual host I am redirected to xampp the url goes to iproject.dev/xampp

I've setup a virtual host as so:

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
127.0.0.1 iproject.dev

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/iProject/public"
ServerName iproject.dev
ServerAlias iproject.dev
ErrorLog "logs/iProject.liog"
CustomLog "logs/custom.iProject.log" combined
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/iProject/public">
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Try using a virtualhost like iproject.dev. It will save you from such issues.

Comment: Setup a [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html), it's better.

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 when I setup a virtual host I get redirected to xampp for some reason though

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 I've updated my question to show how I have tried to setup the virtual host

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use (I've same setup for all of my projects) in `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost iproject.dev>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/iProject/public"
    ServerName iproject.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, add the following line in you `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file

```
127.0.0.2      iproject.dev # 127.0.0.2 could be 127.0.0.3 or ...4/...5
```

For example, this is a part of my `hosts` file in `win-7`

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2       alimsearch.dev # alimsearch.co.uk
127.0.0.3       laravel4.dev
# ...
```

And part of my `httpd-vhosts.conf` file

```
<VirtualHost alimsearch.dev>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/alimsearch/public"
    ServerName alimsearch.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost laravel4.dev>
    DocumentRoot "D:/xampp/htdocs/laravel4/public"
    ServerName laravel4.dev
</VirtualHost>
```