# Laravel 4 Simple Routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have just set up a new laravel 4 project and I can't seem to get my routes to work.

I have the following code in my routes.php file.

```
Route::get('test', function()
{
    return 'test';
}); 

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('hello');
});
```

But if I go to localhost:8888/laravel4 I get a directory listing instead of the '/' route.

If I go to localhost:8888/laravel4/test I get `The requested URL /laravel4/test was not found on this server.`

I am using MAMP with php 5.5.3 for my localhost.

Comment: [Check this answer, setup a irtual host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155671/laravel-setup-failed-to-open-stream/19156780#19156780).

Comment: Seems like a lot of work a fiddling around. Whats the benefit?

Comment: This is how it should be done, recommended way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry point is in the public directory

So you go to 
`localhost:8888/laravel4/public/` 
to get the / route
and 
`localhost:8888/laravel4/public/test` 
to the test route.

Otherwise, you should set up a vhost (Don't know how to do in Mac) and point it to the public directory of your laravel project

Comment: Still not getting anything but blank pages if I use /public. I can access the views I have created but only with their full directory path e.g. localhost:8888/laravel4/app/view/hello.php

Comment: sorry, I meant, localhost:8888/laravel4/public try that

Comment: Yeah thats what I was using.

Comment: @pjmil116 try accessing the index.php file directly

localhost:8888/laravel4/public/index.php
and
localhost:8888/laravel4/public/index.php/test

Comment: mod_rewrite also has to be turned on which maybe your problem.
You can do that through vhost

Comment: LoadModule rewrite_module libexec/apache2/mod_rewrite.so is uncommented in httpd.conf

This should mean it is on?