# virtual host not working as expected

Tags: macos, laravel, virtualhost

I am having trouble setting up a virtual host on Mavericks

First I have this uncommented:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I have my virtual host set up as like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/aaronhappe/Sites/learning-laravel/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   laravel.dev
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

However, when I go to laravel.dev, instead, I see a directory structure exactly the same as if I would go to my local host, rather than my home view to laravel.

Any ideas as to what is wrong?

Comment: I also have restarted my local server.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart your local server?

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Comment: Yes, I did restart my local server as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
<VirtualHost laravel.dev>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/aaronhappe/Sites/learning-laravel/public"
    ServerName laravel.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Host file entry:

```
127.0.0.2   laravel.dev # or 127.0.0.3, an unique IP
```

Restart `apache`. Another [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155671/laravel-setup-failed-to-open-stream/19156780#19156780).