# Laravel generates wrong URLs

Tags: php, laravel

I installed Laravel in a subdirectory, so like:
Root
- mylaravel

When i use the command to generate URLs: {{ URL::route('controller.show', $controller->slug) }}

Its generates an URL like: http:// localhost / controller / show / asdf
But it should be: http:// localhost / mylaravel / controller / show / asdf

In app.php I tried with:

- 'url' => 'http:// localip / phptodomanager'
- 'url' => 'http:// localhost / phptodomanager'

Comment: post your route file.

Comment: Use a virtual host, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155671/laravel-setup-failed-to-open-stream/19156780#19156780).

Answer (score 0):

Use grouping with prefix in routes.php:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'mylaravel'), function() {
    // your routes go here
});
```

as in docs http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-prefixing

Comment: how does grouping helps?

Comment: prefix is added to all generated named routes, what is what you want, or what you asked for at least

Comment: I am not the op. and that `mylaravel` is probably the folder under localhost (most likely scenerio). so it doesn't need grouping. my guess would be, there is some mixing of restful controllers with manuel rotuing.

Comment: Right, mylaravel is a subdirectory. Hope there is an other solution, otherwise i need to wrap all Controller actions in groups?!

Comment: put all the routes in this group, no need to do so for each route. @itachi sorry, didn't notice :)

Comment: Well this very route is wrong, unless you want to got to /phptodomanager/priorities.show. Check this out http://laravel.io/bin/DLnx

Comment: whats about grouping all controller resources? could this work?

Answer (score 0):

you are using a resource controller.

look at the naming convention [**here**](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers).

you **don't** have any route named *controller.show*

a route can be *projects.show* under ProjectController.

you will access it by `http://localhost/mylaravel/projects/show/{project}`

which in controller will be,

```
public function show($project)
{

}
```

you are mixing up all the routes and i am sure, you are also writing your own routes. don't mix resource controller and custom routes. stick to one or the other method unless avoidable.