# Why is my website showing the directory index of my site not the actual site?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, dns

I am tearing my hair out here but my site is showing the list of my sites content and not the site itself on my live site. The .htaccess is what I always use on all of my laravel builds.

**.htaccess**:

```
# The htaccess file
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^{yoursite}.{extension} [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.{yoursite}.{extension}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1 [L]
```

When I go to access the site root I just get a list of files for some reason and its not reading the index.php file in the /public/ folder.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this?

Comment: Try adding `DirectoryIndex index.php` to your htaccess file

Comment: hmm tried adding that to the end of the file and it not working

Comment: Try running the command `php composer install`.

Comment: I wanted to clarify, that you will need to install composer in order to do this.

Comment: yeah I have got all that installed and all packages running from it too

Comment: Better to create a [virtual host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155671/laravel-setup-failed-to-open-stream/19156780#19156780).

Comment: what happens when you go straight to yousite.com/index.php by typing it in?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like PHP is not enabled for the directory. Ensure that your virtual host is configured correctly and also that PHP has mod_rewrite enabled.