# "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." Laravel 4.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, url-routing

Okay, so I've just gotten around to checking out Laravel 4.1, I've hit a problem and I don't understand why? The problem is that I get this message on the screen "Whoops, looks like something went wrong." but I haven't really done anything. I've created a view, a controller and added a route and this is what is in these files

**VIEW**

```
<h1>Author's home page</h1>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class AuthorsController extends BaseController {

    public $restful = true;
    public function getIndex () {
        return View::make('authors.index'); //authors.index because it's in the authors folder within the views folder
    }
}
```

and **ROUTE**

```
Route::get('authors', 'AuthorsController@getIndex');
```

So logic dictates that when I go to the authors URL it should load the getIndex function within the AurhorsController page and show the index.blade.php file which is in views > authors.

If so then I have no idea why this is not working! any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

This is the actual error

```
throw new NotFoundHttpException();
```

**EDIT 2**

[image: Trace]

Comment: `"Whoops, looks like something went wrong."` is a generic text displayed on all error pages. Could you paste the actual error message (look for exception)?

Comment: @MarttiLaine I had debugging turned off, oops this is the error... throw new NotFoundHttpException();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `public $restful = true;` but it's not a problem for `NotFoundHttpException`

```
// Path: app/controllers/AuthorsController.php
class AuthorsController extends BaseController {

    // public $restful = true;

    public function getIndex () {
        return View::make('authors.index');
    }
}
```

According to your `route` given below:

```
Route::get('authors', 'AuthorsController@getIndex');
```

It should work if you make a `GET` request, make sure you made the request from browser's address bar and `url` was like `yourdomain.dev/authors` or `http://localhost/yourapp/authors`. Also you may run following command from command prompt/terminal (within your project directory):

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: ahh thank you! I've fixed it now, also how come your say remove public $restful = true; ?

Comment: Welcome and yes, to declare [RESTful controllers](http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#restful-controllers) you don't need to use `public $restful = true;` in controllers, it was in `version-3`.

Comment: ahh okay thank you makes sense. Another question, do you happen to know how I could remove public directory from the URL?

Comment: Best approach is to use a virtual host, check [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155671/laravel-setup-failed-to-open-stream/19156780#19156780).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Laravel's trying to access the public folder and fails, because there's no file named `authors` in that folder, and also no route named `public/authors`. You'll want to go to `http://localhost:8081/branch/authors` instead, assuming that your installation resides in `http://localhost:8081/branch`.